# Using Sphinx's spellcheck in very large databases

Tags: sphinx

How do I implement Sphinx's companion Suggest feature on databases with large numbers of rows?

Right now, Sphinx's Suggest feature works fine on around 1,000 rows. But I am afraid that actually using Suggest, on a database with hundreds of thousands of rows, will not work out well especially if there are  new rows are added regularly (say, 100 at a time). My database also contains very specific and technical terms, so I need to actually lower the frequency limit from the default 40 to 1.

How should I work on this? My primary concern is that using by using suggest.php --builddict, I am actually rewriting the whole suggest table from scratch. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I use it for tables with 75k rows, without problem. takes about 10 seconds of processing. What specific issue are you facing?